# Save TimeZone with Date in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, java.util.date

I have java.util.Date field in my document class.

E:g:

```
@Document(collection = "testdoc")
public class TestDoc {
    @Id
    String id;
    Date startDate;
}
```

Even if I set the Date with UTC and IST, it always save in my collection as below,

```
 "startDate" : ISODate("2015-08-21T18:30:00.000Z")
```

How can I save the time zone also in mongo collection? What does Z stand in this case?

Comment: Warning: the solution by Anirudh and Yonatan from the official documentation are aimed at querying the database on local times, which is hackish and may or may not be your use case. Be aware that it looks like Javascript Date object actually does not store timezone information. You did not state if you need to perform queries based on local times. My use case is okay with querying UTC, I just want to access the full original date with timezone. In that case the simplest is to store two fields: the ISODate for UTC querying, a ISO-8601 string.

Answer (score 11):

The 'Z' signifies that the time is stored in UTC. Mongo internally converts all local representations of time in UTC before storing. However, one suggestion would be to store the time along with the timezone which is received from your application. You can later reconstruct the local time from the UTC time and the timezone in your application logic.

Please go through this link. They have given an example on how to model local time data using JavaScript.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/model-time-data/

Answer (score 10):

Do the conversion before storing and save as UTC always. Then reconvert it in the timezone you want before displaying.

If you desperately want to store the timezone with the offset you may have to deal with it as a separate string in db, but it cannot go with date field for MongoDB.

As currently MongoDB doesn't allow saving of timezone.
Below is the open JIRA issue or the same.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6310

Comment: Saving, Loading and Displaying are different things. Let's say the timestamps have been recorded in India, stored in UTC time and now displayed in Europe. In this case you don't want to convert the UTC time to European time, but you wanna see the original Indian time. But you're right, you need to store the timezone in a separate field. [Example here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-time-data/).

Comment: @Matthias this is a good scenario when you want to store in the db for a specific timezone, not UTC. So when you see raw data, it would be in that desired timezone always. But as for displaying data back, one should reconvert to UTC and apply timezones properly

Comment: The problem in storing UTC only is, that you are losing the original timezone information which makes it difficult to re-use the timestamp for specific scenarios. Displaying in the users current timezone might be a different timezone than where the data has been recorded.

Answer (score 2):

Dates in MongoDB are stored in UTC. There isn't timestamp with a timezone data type like in some relational databases. Applications that need to access and modify timestamps, based on local time, should store the timezone offset together with the date and offset dates on an application level.

In the MongoDB shell, this could be done using the following format with JavaScript:

```
let now = new Date();
db.page_views.save({date: now,                    
                    offset: now.getTimezoneOffset()});
```

Then you need to apply the saved offset to reconstruct the original local time, as in the following example:

```
let record = db.page_views.findOne();
let localNow = new Date( record.date.getTime() - ( record.offset * 60000 ) );
```

Comment: This is straight from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-time-data/#example . Warning: the reconstructed Date object represents the original instant in time, but it is not expressed in the time zone of the original computer, as Javascript Date cannot do that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/timezone/) you'll find a good guideline how to handle timestamps in different scenarios for different data language independent. 
As it's recommendet in the document, ALWAYS use UTC to save the data, even it is local timezone. If necessary, save the time zone in a seperate field ( JSON or xml) and follw the format guideline ISO 8601. ( like you did but there are many possible representations) 
As far as I know, correct me if i'm wrong, JSOn does not deal with specific date formats but JS does. Microsoft docs recommends the followind format bases on ECMA `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/ie_standards/ms-es3ex/e13c8110-e94f-49ef-9316-0bef4dd05833) 
The Z in the Timestamp shows that it's UTC format with zero offset +00:00 
if nothing else is added.
If you want to use the "Z" notation, you have to add or substract the offset within the timestamp instead of writing the zero-offset and add the offset at the end.
I recommend you to follw the w3c guideline because it covers different scenatios for different time saving usecases. 
Hope this helps