# Nodejs Mongoose : Trying to save date in UTC Timezone but its saving in local time zone

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, datetime, mongoose

I am new for nodejs and mongodb. I am using mongoose for mongodb and I am facing the issue related date whenever I try to save date into database it automatically convert into local timezone, however it should not be happen.

I have set Node timezone "UTC" into .env file and it is working when I do console.log(new Date()), it returns me the current datetime according to UTC. But when I trying to save it to mongoose it converted into localtime zone. I have tried it with **Date** field as well with **timestamps : true** it convert both into local timezone.

My code is
**// Mongoose model**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var activitySchema = new Schema({
    'userId': Number,
    'data': Array,
    'otherDetails': Array,
    'date':Date
}, {
    timestamps: false
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('activity', activitySchema);
```

// Save code

```
let na = new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '')+".100";
 var activity = new activityModel({
            userId : req.user.user_id,
            otherDetails : req.body.otherDetails,
            data : req.body.data,
            date : na.toString()

        });

        activity.save();
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40502686/save-timezone-with-date-in-mongodb?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), it seems like Mongo automatically saves all dates in UTC.  Therefore, you would need to have a transformation somewhere to convert into the time zone you are looking for.  Alternatively, you could just store the date as a string and parse it into a date after being read from the DB.